# Is there a standard reverseLookup function?

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for something with the following function signature

```
Eq b => b -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe a
```

Comment: That’s just `\x -> lookup x . map swap`, where `swap` is from `Data.Tuple`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the function [`find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:find) from the module Data.List from the base package. Unfortunately, I can't test the code right now but it could go like this:

```
sndLookup :: Eq b => b -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe a
sndLookup query = fst <$> find (\(_,b) -> b == query)
```